# How to fill an array-struct with class objects?

Tags: c++, oop

i`m having this structure(array) which i want to fill with Class objects. What is the procedure to acomplish that. The tutorials i used/books weren't that detailed and i don't know how to do that.(since my tries failed)

ARRAY STRUCT 
struct.h

```
struct Arr{

    int days;
    int *M;
};
typedef Arr* Array;
```

struct.cpp

```
void constr(Array &o){
    //Construct of 1*31 Matrix
    o=new Arr;
    o->days = days;
    o->M = new int[o->days];
```

CLASS

expe.h

```
class Expe {
private:
    int *obj;

public:
    Expe();
    ~Expe();

    void setObj(int ,int ,int ,int ,int ,int);
    void printObj();
    int getObj();
enter code here
```

expe.cpp

```
Expe::Expe() {
    this->obj=new int[6];
}

Expe::~Expe() {
    delete this->obj;
}
```

ps: I need to use my own struct vector.h is not allowed, and it has to be dyanmical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code is now, your `Arr` struct can hold an array of integers. If you want it to hold `Expe` objects you can define it as:

```
struct Arr{
    int days;
    Expe* M;
};
```

or, better yet, make it a template class:

```
template<typename T>
struct Arr
{
    int _size;
    T* M;
};
```

I also suggest moving the constructor *inside* the `struct` instead of the method `constr`:

```
template<typename T>
struct Arr
{
    int _size;
    T* M;
    Arr(int size) : _size(size)
    {
        M = new T[size];
    }
    //manage the memory:
    ~Arr()
    {
        delete[] M;
    }
};
```

By using a template, you can specialize `Arr` however you want:

```
Arr<int> x(10);  //creates an array of 10 int's
Arr<Expe> y(10); //creates an array of 10 Expe's
```

As a side-note, since this isn't PHP, the `this->` is not really necessary inside the class context, unless you have a local variable with the same name as a member, which you don't.

Comment: thank you, for now i need to get used to templates, i do not anything about them... really helpful, going to study a bit about templates :D